# sshd error: no more sessions

Tags: sshd, session

I see many lines in /var/log/auth.log about sshd sessions, like below

```
Mar 25 11:04:47 hosting-prd sshd[7882]: error: no more sessions
Mar 25 11:04:47 hosting-prd sshd[7882]: error: no more sessions
Mar 25 11:04:47 hosting-prd sshd[7882]: error: no more sessions
```

I tried to increase more messages with "LogLevel VERBOSE" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, but still no more hints.

Comment: Bump the `LogLevel` to `DEBUG3` and post the context of this message. It is general error when call to `session_new()` fails. There are more debug information describing what went wrong around.

Comment: It seems to be answered here:
http://serverfault.com/questions/182847/count-ssh-sessions

Comment: Here is the log with LogLevel DEBUG3 applied:

http://pastebin.com/hxrFBJ2r

Comment: Netstat results: http://pastebin.com/SBBHvE44